# Integrating Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm making an app and i want integrated Facebook, but this error can't continue, attached my problem.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true

    }
    func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation:annotation)    }  THIS IS THE PROBLEM  -- > ////Use of unresolved identifier "sourceApplication"///
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the Facebook framework?

Comment: @Adolfo that isn't the problem.  The problem is this user copied and pasted the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` call into the iOS 8 delegate without understanding how `openURL` and URL schemes work.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate method does not match the one being used by Facebook.  What about something like this?

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```